# Программная аутентификация в ЕСИА

Tags: есиа

Имеется программа, которая ранее тянула данные со страницы [Ссылка на страницу Роспотребнадзора](https://roszdravnadzor.ru/opendata/7710537160-licenses)

и выгружала оттуда некоторые данные. Но с недавнего времени данная ссылка стала нерабочей. Я написал в Росздравнадзор вопрос о том, почему ссылка стала не рабочей и как мне найти данные, которые ранее были доступны по вышеуказанной ссылке. На что получил следующий ответ:

*В рамках исполнения перечня поручений Заместителя Председателя Правительства
Российской Федерации Чернышенко Д.Н. от 26 декабря 2022 г. № ДЧ-П10-22463 и
рекомендациями Минэкономразвития России набор данных «Реестр лицензий
Росздравнадзора» размещен на сайте Росздравнадзора в Личном кабинете
Росздравнадзора (справа наверху) с авторизацией в Единой системе
идентификации и аутентификации (ЕСИА, учетная запись от Портала госуслуг) в
рубрике «Открытые данные» (слева) и доступен по ссылке:*
https://gosuslugi.roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/opendata/meta/uid/7710537160-licenses

*С уважением,
техническая поддержка Интернет-портала Росздравнадзора*

При открытии ссылки https://gosuslugi.roszdravnadzor.gov.ru/opendata/meta/uid/7710537160-licenses автоматически происходит редирект на страницу "https://esia.gosuslugi.ru/login/". Если в браузере ввести свой логин и пароль (и затем еще ввести код из смс) от Госуслуг, то произойдет автоматическое перенаправление на нужную мне страницу.

Поэтому возникает вопрос: что необходимо сделать для того, чтобы можно было бы программно авторизоваться в ЕСИА, чтобы программно получить доступ к нужной мне странице?